# Преобразовать объект JS, для отправки на сервер

Tags: javascript, jquery, алгоритм

По какому алгоритму можно преобразовать объект, для отправки XMLHttpRequest POST, с заголовком application/x-www-form-urlencoded? В объект может быть любой уровень вложенности. Например такой объект:

```
let obj = {
  a: 0,
  b: 1,
  c: [
    "A", "B",
    {0:"z", 1:"x"}
  ]
}
```

должен быть преобразован в такую строку: `a=0&b=1&c[]=A&c[]=B&c[2][]=z&c[2][]=x`.
Сложности возникают с неизвестным уровнем вложенности. Пытался посмотреть как это делает JQuery при отправке через `$.ajax()`, но не смог разобраться.

Comment: Стандартная отправка в формате `JSON`, вам не подходит?

Comment: @KostaB c такой отправкой все просто закодировать на клиенте раскодировать на сервере. На самом деле это абстрактная задача, просто стало интересно разобраться как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться форматом JSON.
JSON - это строковый формат объектов в javascript.
Метод `JSON.stringify(obj)` превращает объект в строку формата JSON, а метод `JSON.parse(str)` наоборот.
Подробнее https://learn.javascript.ru/json

Comment: По поводу этого @KostaB писал, это не то.